# MS Access 2013: When splitting a database... sub-sub-related (+ sign) records disappear

Tags: database, ms-access-2013

After splitting database, form with a subform/table that had sub-related records (+ sign) no longer appear. Worked fine prior to the split.
Any help... much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the table relationships are defined in your back end database and double check that your subform has the Link Master/Child fields set.